# Promises and methods

Tags: jquery

I wish to chain a series of promises, but i wish to define each promise in it's own method.

Here are my methods:

```
p.methodOne = function() {

  var prm_dataCount = $.ajax({'get-data'});

  prm_dataCount.done(function(data){p.dataCount = data;});

}

p.methodTwo = function() {

  var prm_dataCountTwo = $.ajax({'get-data-two'});

  prm_dataCountTwo.done(function(data){p.dataCountTwo = data;});

}
```

And I wish to call them such as:

```
this.methodOne().then(this.methodOne);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to have your methods *return* the promise, so that you can chain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *return* the promise from the methods for this to work.

```
p.methodOne = function() {
  var prm_dataCount = $.ajax({'get-data'});
  prm_dataCount.done(function(data){p.dataCount = data;});
  return prm_dataCount;
}

p.methodTwo = function() {
  var prm_dataCountTwo = $.ajax({'get-data-two'});
  prm_dataCountTwo.done(function(data){p.dataCountTwo = data;});
  return prm_dataCountTwo;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
this.methodOne().then(this.methodTwo);
```